# Finding subarray with given sum

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

The problem statement is:

> Given an unsorted array of nonnegative integers, find a continous subarray which adds to a given number.

```
Examples:

Input: arr[] = {1, 4, 20, 3, 10, 5}, sum = 33
Ouptut: Sum found between indexes 2 and 4

Input: arr[] = {1, 4, 0, 0, 3, 10, 5}, sum = 7
Ouptut: Sum found between indexes 1 and 4

Input: arr[] = {1, 4}, sum = 0
Output: No subarray found
```

Based on the an explanation of a solution from [this post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/) the following solution wouldn't work for negative numbers:

```
/* An efficient program to print subarray with sum as given sum */
#include<stdio.h>

/* Returns true if the there is a subarray of arr[] with sum equal to 'sum'
   otherwise returns false.  Also, prints the result */
int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    /* Initialize curr_sum as value of first element
       and starting point as 0 */
    int curr_sum = arr[0], start = 0, i;

    /* Add elements one by one to curr_sum and if the curr_sum exceeds the
       sum, then remove starting element */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // If curr_sum exceeds the sum, then remove the starting elements
        while (curr_sum > sum && start < i-1)
        {
            curr_sum = curr_sum - arr[start];
            start++;
        }

        // If curr_sum becomes equal to sum, then return true
        if (curr_sum == sum)
        {
            printf ("Sum found between indexes %d and %d", start, i-1);
            return 1;
        }

        // Add this element to curr_sum
        if (i < n)
          curr_sum = curr_sum + arr[i];
    }

    // If we reach here, then no subarray
    printf("No subarray found");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried considering a few different scenarios of inputs but I couldn't think of a case where the input array would contain negative numbers and not yield the correct output. Here is one input array with negative numbers that works:

```
int arr[] = { 15, 14, -2, 3, -5, 14};
```

**Which input cases is the post referring to when it says that the solution won't work for negative numbers?**

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  The debugger will help show you the values in variables as you execute your program, statement by statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution relies on this fact that when we remove an element our sum decreases but having a negative number contradicts with this assumption.
 The shortest examples are cases like this 
`-1 5 2` when we are looking for subarrays with sum of 5. The operation will be as follows:

```
add -1, sum = -1
add 5, sum = 4
add 2, sum = 6
remove -1, sum = 7
remove 5, sum = 2
```

We have reached the end of the list but we haven't found the desired subarray.

Answer (score 1):

The  algorithm will fail if the sum between the start and end of the subarray exceeds the total it's looking for. This will occur if the last value or values of the subarray are negative.

For example,

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 7, -5, 0 };
subArraySum(arr, 5, 5);
```

will fail

Answer (score 0):

That while loop checks the current sum, and if it exceeds the target sum it removes the start element and continues with the next ones (an optimization). Adding a negative value, will make the sum smaller, so this technique doesn't work, as the assumption that adding an element increases the sum (and it may thus exceed the target sum) isn't valid.

If you want to modify the algorithm so as to allow negative values as well, no optimizations are possible, and you have to check the sum from every element till the end of the array (a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm).

Comment: actually, you can still do O(n) if you use a hashtable

Comment: Hash table here? How and why? The array is ordered. And I'm not sure about the additional overhead of creating the hash table, binding it the to the input table and destroying it either. Could you elaborate?

Comment: [read this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum-in-array-of-integers/)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 7;
int arr[] = {-2,5,5,-1,7};
```

-2 + 5 + 5 = 8;

At this point the algorithm assumes that we decrease our current sum by removing -2 , but in fact , it will increase to 10. The correct move here is to add -1 to the mix and have our solution, but the algorithm misses it.

With positive integers , we would never need that -2 again , because the algorithm figures the the current sum was already too high and will only get higher by advancing further to the right.with negative values , that assumption does not hold.